# Настроить консоль интерпретатора replit.com для ввода кода на Python, в режиме базового интерпретатора

Tags: python, интерпретатор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день, друзья. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить консоль интерпретатора replit.com для построчного ввода кода на Python, в режиме базового интерпретатора со строкой приглашения '>>>,' ? Ранее была настройка, сейчас слетела. На верхнем рисунке, то как сейчас, а нужно как на рисунке ниже с оранжевыми знаками приглашения.

Comment: А можно как-то по другому? 0_O

Comment: можете создать файл .replit в корневой директории вашего проекта и добавить в него следующий код: run = 'python -i -q'

Comment: Не добавляйте лишние метки в вопрос. Я уверен, что вы не используете ни python 3.5, ни python 3.6. Python 3.8 тоже не нужно добавлять (если вдруг вы собирались это сделать), просто метки python уже достаточно.

Comment: Beneviento:
Не помогло